# Best practice for ASP.NET MVC webshop search-engine with SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, search-engine, webshop

We developing a webshop with a SQL Server database in the background and have an internal discussion about the best way to integrate/create a search engine.

At the moment we discuss following approaches:

1. SQL Server full-text search

   - PRO: Fast!
   - CON: often bad results, because of language problems (german) or technical 
     abbreviation,...
2. Lucene.Net

   - PRO: Fast, good results..
   - CON: Outdated (last release 3.0.3 - Oct 10, 2012) ???
3. Web caching (HttpRuntine.Cache) / Linq searching (was only an idea to cache all search data via hangfire framework and make a classic linq search)

Comment: You should use elastic search. https://www.elastic.co/products/elasticsearch

Comment: I agree with elastic

Comment: interesting!!! and its completly open source and fre?? it's kind of too good to be true :D